# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file

Tags: android, emulation

When I run the emulator I get an error message in the event log of the android studio:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\dell.android\avd\Nexus_5X_API_24.avd/userdata.img

Comment: Try making another emulator device

Comment: This issue is not related to your code or programming in any ways, it's clearly related to the emulator itself, i suggest you to ask this on android-studio's community forums.